# C++ rbegin modify address of reverse_iterator

Tags: c++, reverse-iterator

I have a strange problem in c++ with this code:

```
mutex_type  list_mutex;
typedef list<char*> RQueue;
RQueue rQueue;
RQueue::reverse_iterator  rstart, rend, last;

  1  while(true) {
  2      LockMutex(list_mutex);
  3      rstart = rQueue.rbegin();
  4      rend   = rQueue.rend();
  5      while( (rstart != rend) && (rstart != last) ) {
  6           print *rstart;
  7      }
  8      last = rQueue.rbegin(); 
  9      UnlockMutex(list_mutex);
  10  }
```

- `rQueue` is a queue in which I iterate in reverse order
- `rQueue` can receive messages at any time
- I added the iterator `last` in order to
  avoid reworking with a receive message at line 6
- At line 8, I retain the position from where I printed the messages and I want to
  only print the messages that are newer than the last message.

  My problem: When a iteration is finished and new messages are added in
  the queue, the value of iterator `last` is changed, becoming the same
  as the value of the iterator `rstart`, therefore the new arrived
  messages are not printed at line 6.

I don't know why `last = rQueue.rbegin()` modifies its value when receiving new elements after unlocking the queue.

Thanks.

Comment: Although [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19826255/why-does-insert-invalidate-the-stdset-reverse-iterator/19826483) is not really a duplicate, my answer there answers the question you have here.

Comment: Not that the `while` statement will mean exactly the same thing if you remove two-thirds of the parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set an iterator to `rbegin()`, it will always keep pointing to the last element of the list. If you add another element at the back, the iterator will point still point to the last element (which now is the new one). It will not change, it just keeps pointing to the end.

I did this test:

```
list<const char *> my_list;
my_list.push_back("msg 1");

list<const char*>::reverse_iterator it = my_list.rbegin();

cout << "Iterator is " << *it << endl;

my_list.push_back("msg 2");
my_list.push_back("msg 3");
my_list.push_back("msg 4");

cout << "Iterator is " << *it << endl;
```

This program gives the output:

```
Iterator is msg 1
Iterator is msg 4
```

I have this other solution you might use which does not use a reverse iterator. Instead, the `addMessage()`-function updates `read_pos` to the newest message. If `read_pos` does not point to the end, it is not changed either. This allows `printMessage()` to print all messages which where added since last time it ran.

Notice that I have only tested this without the locking.

```
mutex_type  list_mutex;
typedef list<const char*> RQueue;
RQueue rQueue;

RQueue::iterator read_pos;

void addMessage(const char *message) {
    LockMutex(list_mutex);

    rQueue.push_back(message);

    if (rQueue.size() == 1) {
        read_pos = rQueue.begin();
    }
    else if (read_pos == rQueue.end()) {
        read_pos--;
    }

    UnlockMutex(list_mutex);
}

void printMessage() {
  RQueue::iterator prev_pos;

  while (true) {
    LockMutex(list_mutex);

    if (rQueue.size() == 0) {
          UnlockMutex(list_mutex);
          continue;
    }

    RQueue::iterator end = rQueue.end();
    while (read_pos != end) {
        cout << *read_pos << endl;
        read_pos++;
    }

    UnlockMutex(list_mutex);
  }
}
```