# Erasing an element in std::multiset caused irrelevant iterator invalid

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include<set>
std::multiset<int>s;
int main() {
    s.insert(1);
    s.insert(2);
    s.insert(3);
    for (auto i=s.rbegin();i!=s.rend();++i) {
        auto j=s.lower_bound(*i<<1);
        if (j!=s.end())s.erase(j);
    }
}
```

This program crashes and I got an error says "map/set iterator not decrementable". I thought since all elements are positive integers, then `*i<<1` will be larger than `*i`, hence the pointed position of `j` will be different from `i`. And according to the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/erase):

> References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. Other
>   references and iterators are not affected.

Since the pointed position of `i` and `j` are different, erasing `j` won't affect `i` and the loop. So I am confused why it is wrong.

Environment: Windows10 x86, Visual Studio 2015 Update 3

Comment: Try explicitly comparing `i != j` and see if your reasoning about their distinctiveness actually holds.

Comment: @Novelocrat : `i.base() != j` since he's dealing with reverse iterators.

Comment: @Novelocrat  I've added output for `*i` and `*j` in `j != s.end()` and only see `1 2` as expected.

Comment: This question is probably close enough to [this other one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19826255/why-does-insert-invalidate-the-stdset-reverse-iterator) to close it as a dupe.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the iterator is invalid is that your loop erased it, and the subsequent `for` iteration is using that invalidated iterator on the increment portion of the loop.

If you run this using the debugger, you will see that when the `erase()` is invoked, the iterator `i` is pointing to the same element as iterator `j`.  You now `s.erase(j)`, and `i` is also invalidated.  On the `++i` in the loop iteration, an attempt to increment an invalid iterator is done, thus the error.

```
s.insert(1);
s.insert(2);
s.insert(3);
for (auto i = s.rbegin(); i != s.rend(); 
     ++i) // <-- It's this that is causing the issue
{
    auto j = s.lower_bound(*i << 1);
    if (j != s.end())
        s.erase(j);  // <-- If `i` is pointing to this element, iteration becomes invalidated
}
```

So basically, you're trying to perform `++` on something that doesn't exist.  Since you're using Visual Studio (going by the error given), if you go to the assembly window when debugging, you see that it is indeed the `++` operation that is triggering the error.

---

See this on iterator invalidation: [multiset::erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/erase) and note this in the link:

**References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated.**